# LDAP disable user

Tags: ldap, openldap, password-policy

I'm using Apache Directory Ldap with openLDAP 2.5.12.

I want to set a attribue like AD userAccountControl UF ACCT DISABLED value, which means it can show the user is available or not.
At frist, I got informations that can add Object passwordPolicy in the right schema.However,there isn't the ppolicy.schema in /etc/ldap/schema and I can't to add the ppolicy.schema with the SFTP error.

I am wonder how can I do?
Or there are some objects with some attribute can replace?

Thank you SO much!

Comment: My installations of OpenLDAP have all certainly come with `ppolicy.schema` for over a decade: and SFTP errors  have nothing to do with LDAP. Off topic.

Comment: @user207421 Hi, I am wonder why I haven't ppolicy.schema, but that's fine I copyed from google. It's work!